# Copy all the cells in a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a sheet which has 200 rows with some blanks in between.

I cannot use `End(xlDown)` or `End(xlUp)` to get the entire range because there are blank rows.

How can I copy up to the last range which has data in columns?

Also, I don't want to copy the headers.

Kindly suggest how I can do this in Excel VBA.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that you demonstrate some effort with a specific programming problem. _Simply asking for code, which you have done in several questions already, is frowned upon_. If you don't have any sample code, spend more time learning the language and come back with a specific problem. Break the problem down into smaller steps and do searches for how to solve those problems. If you are stuck on those, ask here. But placing orders for code simply won't work here.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to copy them is to use Autofilter and filter them on Blanks and then copy the visible range

For Example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rngToCopy As Range, rRange As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rRange = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rRange 'Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and copy visible rows
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
            Set rngToCopy = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        rngToCopy.Copy

        '
        '~~> Rest of the Code
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the last used row in column A of the active sheet with the code below (it works also if you have blank cells in the middle of the column) - amend as required if you need to run it on a different sheet / column.

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy 'copies column A used range, excluding header row
End With
```