# Blanks rows after cutting from a filtered range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm using the below code to setup a filter and cut certain data from the filter and put it into another tab.

However I have two issues:

1. When I Cut the data (I'm using `.EntireRow.Cut`) from the filtered sheet I'm left with blank rows in the filter.  **How can I cut the data without leaving blank rows?**
2. I want to `Cut` the filter data (Excluding the header in row 1).  I can't use offset or `.Resize` as it takes me to a hidden row (not included in the filter range).  **How do I get around this?**

Code is:

```
Lcol = FindLastCol(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName)
Lrow = FindLastRow(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName)
Set rngToCheck = Range(Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(1, 1), _
    Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(Lrow, Lcol)).Rows


FieldNum = Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells.Find(What:=gcsSearchFund, After:=[a1], LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column


Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Rows(1).AutoFilter


rngToCheck.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:= _
    "=*[2]*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="


Lrow = FindLastRow(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName)
LrowRT = FindLastRow(gcsRemovedInvestors)


Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Range(Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(1, 1), _
    Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(Lrow, 1)).EntireRow.Cut Sheets(gcsRemovedInvestors).Cells(LrowRT, 1)
```

Comment: After cutting, you cant sort the data? That would push the blank data to the bottom...

Comment: I could - it will add a little to the routine but it's a solution.  I have about 15 filters to cut out.  I will nee to work out the 2nd question (headers) before I go with this.  Do you know how to get around seelcting the the second row in the range I want to cut?  If I use .offset or .resize it takes me to a hidden row?  Also do you know how to cut just visable rows?  P.S  Thanks for support.

Comment: Yes, I have answered a similar questions in the past... One moment, let me search for it

Comment: Here is one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416831/copy-all-the-cells-in-a-column/11417354#11417354

Comment: Thank you so much - I will work with this.  I appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Hi Siddharth - can you select answered so I can credit this answer to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thats Ok. You can post the answer that you arrived at select it as an answer :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you Siddharth - I'm going into "Responses" / Selecting your first response but it's not giving me an option on the Left hand side to tick as answered.  Am I doing something wrong?  This has never happened to me before but I want to make sure I credit this as I appreciate the help.

Comment: You have to post an answer first below and then select it as an answer :)

Comment: It's like I'm taking credit for your work.  Thanks for help.

Comment: NO you are not :) All I did was just gave you some suggestions and a link to another post :)

Answer (score 1):

With the full support of Siddharth Rout I have managed to resolve this issue:

I have used the following:

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

This allowed me to select only the visable cells to cut.

I setup and dynamic range and used `.Resize` to unselect the header so I cut only the data that I had filtered.

Thanks again for support.

Ciaran.