# excel vba null value in array

Tags: vba, excel

my code is

```
          Sub sch()
          Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
          Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
          Dim wb3 As Excel.Workbook
          Dim arr1() As Variant
          Dim arr2() As Variant
          Dim arr3() As Variant
          Set wb1 = Workbooks("Contractor Manpower Tracking_NE_02.06.2015.xlsx")
          arr1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3:D89").Value
          Workbooks("k.xlsm").Activate

          For Row = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
               For col = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
                    If Not arr1(Row, col) = " " Then
                         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row + 1, 1) = arr1(Row, col)
                    End If
              Next col
           Next Row
         End Sub
```

I want to eliminate null values in cells but the some of the cells are remaining blank.Please help

Comment: and what about ```trim(arr1(Row, col)) = ""``` ?

Comment: the data which i am taking from different sheet is in single as well as merged cell format

Comment: Why are you looping through the array. Write the array in one go as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725472/texttocolumns-function-uses-wrong-delimiter/30726233#30726233) Then use `.Autofilter` to delete blank rows? You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416831/copy-all-the-cells-in-a-column/11417354#11417354)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get NULL values (very specific type) when you extract from databases

One way to deal with those NULL values in Excel is like this

```
If IsNull(arr1(Row, col)) Then arr1(Row, col) = vbNullString
```

other than that, both suggestions in comments are good:

```
If Not Len(trim(arr1(Row, col))) = 0 Then ...
```

Merged cells can cause you unexpected issues: for example you'll have to determine how a value from 3 vertical cells merged in Sheet2 will map to one cell in Sheet1 (most likely you'll want the same value populated in 3 cells in Sheet1)